# Add JScrollPane to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

In my program one user should fill a "Object" field with text of an arbitrary length. 
So I'd like to create a JTextArea with reasonable dimensions and with an associated JSrollPane in order to read all the inserted text, if it's very long. This is what I've done:

```
    body.add(new JLabel("OGGETTO"), "1,2");

    JTextArea oggetto = new JTextArea(5,20);
    oggetto.setOpaque(true);
    oggetto.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    Border borderOgg = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
    oggetto.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(borderOgg,
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)));

    oggetto.setLineWrap(true);
    oggetto.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(oggetto);
    scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    body.add(scroll1,"3,2");

    body.add(oggetto, "2,2");
```

where body is a JPanel whose layout is TableLayout.
But the scroll doesn't work even if it's showed.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove below line

```
body.add(oggetto, "2,2");
```

because `JTextArea` is already added in `JScrollPane` hence there is no need to add it again.

Comment: Ok, that's right. Thank you...so, when we add a JScrollPane to an element, we don't have to add the element to the jpanel body right?

Comment: thanks very much...this wasn't clear to me. as soon as possible I'll accept your answer...it says I have to wait for 12 minutes before :S

Comment: I just want to point out that theres a minor typo, I believe it should be `JTextArea` not `JTaxtArea`

Comment: +1 @LoryLory `when we add a JScrollPane to an element, we don't have to add the element to the jpanel body right?` - actually you are adding a "component" (please use the proper terminology) to the scrollpane. And you can't add the component to the panel because a component can only have a single parent, so if you add the component to the panel it will be removed from the scrollpane.